# Unexpected center alignment of the text after the remark block

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ieeetran

I am working on a draft within an `ieeetran` template. There are a couple of definitions and remarks within the text, have which been embedded, deservedly. But the odd thing is that, as I try to continue the rest of the text after the last remark, the text is aligned centered, even though there is no `\centering` or `\center{}` block!...

Here is the challenging snippet after the remark:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Background}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Some text...

\bigskip

\begin{rem}
\centering
My remark body...
\end{rem}

\bigskip

The aforementioned definitions... %It has been aligned Centered!!!

\end{document}
```

Would you please enlightening me to reset the aforementioned centered alignment to the common form of the latex document?!...

Edit: I completed the script...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code snippet you have given has no problems. For example, `\documentclass{ieeetran}\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}\begin{document}\begin{rem}My remark body...\end{rem}\lipsum[2]\end{document}`. Please complete it to a full one to show the problem.

Comment: @percusse: I did complete the code... Would you please sharing any idea about the possible problem?!...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: This is caused by including unneeded packages. LaTeX has a little known easter egg: When you include too many unneeded packages too often, some lines of your document will be centered. Obviously this effect can not be repeated by users who always create [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found the case...

The effect of the `\centering` command after the `remark` is still supposed to be taken into account.

With replacing that with `\begin{center}something\end{center}`, the problem just vanished...

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem here. Using `\centering` inside the `rem` is taking effect only inside it.

Comment: @Sigur: You might be right... However, the case has just been resolved with the aforementioned change... That could be a bug!